# How to create a fab button in vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to create a position fixed/absolute fab button on bottom right of page in vuetify.

I have this

```
    <v-btn fab dark large color="primary">
        <v-icon dark>add</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
```

but it puts the button as left aligned and not fixed.

Comment: you want a fixed button like that in vuetify website at the right bottom

Comment: yeah basically that

Comment: figured it out.

Answer (score 27):

```
    <v-btn fab dark large color="primary" fixed right bottom>
        <v-icon dark>add</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i have been trying to align my fab on the bottom right for an hour, and it was overflowing the viewport. I was using `absolute`, when i changed to `fixed` it solved my problem !

Comment: It fixed my problem :D